# Unused global option (cleardoublepage=plain)

Tags: koma-script, warnings

I know that some of the `Unused global option(s)` LaTeX warnings can be resolved including some packages (as in [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=625)). Specifically, How can I get rid of the following warning?

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [cleardoublepage=plain].
```

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: It is a modified ABNT (brazilian standard, available as abntex).

Comment: It's a specific option for the KoMa classes, so it doesn't apply to any package in particular and with the ABNT class it's useless.

Comment: It means I can remove this setting from the class file? (Also, place your comment as an answer so I can accept it - if you wish).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option `cleardoublepage=plain` is specific to classes from the KOMA-Script bundle (`scrartcls`, `scrreprt` and `scrbook`). I know of no other class or package that knows how to interpret it.

Remove the option, if you're not using such a document class.